# no puedo levantar json server en react

Tags: nodejs, json, reactjs, npm, server

el problema es que no me encuentra el archivo en el directorio pero si existe y si la estoy pasando bien a la ruta
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```
PS C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing> npx json-server --watch /src/assets/json/db.json

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading /src/assets/json/db.json
  Oops, /src/assets/json/db.json doesn't seem to exist
  Creating /src/assets/json/db.json with some default data

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/assets/json/db.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1524:35)
    at C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\utils\load.js:44:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\utils\load.js:38:10)
    at start (C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js:112:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js:149:3)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\index.js:86:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sntlg\OneDrive\Escritorio\KMV-Clothing\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\bin.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/src/assets/json/db.json'`introducir el código aquí`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Qgw.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en como estás llamando a la ruta. El `/` inicial en `/src/assets/json/db.json` hace que busque una ruta absoluta respecto a tu disco (estaría buscando algo como `C:/src/assets/json/db.json`)

Ponle un `.` u omite el `/` para inidicar que es una ruta relativa a donde estás parado al ejecutar el comando:

```
npx json-server --watch ./src/assets/json/db.json
npx json-server --watch src/assets/json/db.json
```